# How to Add osm Coordinates to my Collection in meteor

Tags: meteor, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am working on a simple map on a dashboard that registers click events and save the locations into a collection and also creates a marker on the location clicked. However, only the locations clicked get saved and the markers do not show up. Here is my code below

```js
Template.osm.onRendered(function(){
    var map = L.map('osm-container', {
        center: [6.54, 3.33],
        zoom: 13
    });
    var markers = {};
    var id;

    L.tileLayer('http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Imagery from <a href="http://mapbox.com/about/maps/">MapBox</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        id: 'REMOVED',
        accessToken: 'REMOVED'
    }).addTo(map);
    var coordinates = {};
    map.on('click', function(event) {
        var randm = Math.ceil(10000*Math.random());
        var entry = Coordinates.insert({ 
              lat: event.latlng.lat,
              lng: event.latlng.lng,
              seq: randm });
        id = entry;
    });


    Coordinates.find().observe({
        added: function (document) {
            L.marker({ lat: Coordinates.find({_id:id},{lat:1, _id:0}), 
                       lng: Coordinates.find({_id:id},{lng:1,_id:0}) },{
                clickable : true,
                draggable: true,
                keyboard: true,
                riseOnHover: true
            }).addTo(map);

            map.on('dragend', function(event) {
                todo
            });

            // markers[id] = mark;
        },
        changed: function(newDocument, oldDocument) {
            // todo;
        },
        removed: function (oldDocument) {
            // todo 
        }
    });
});
```

Please can anyone help

Comment: I removed your user id and access token, since they seemed to be sensitive

Comment: This is quite possibly related to the scope where `map` is defined. Try declaring `var map = null;` in the global scope and then replace `var map = L.map..` with `map = L.map..`.

Comment: Thanks Christian for removing my user id and access token, I don't know how that escaped me. Will try the advised steps.

Comment: I just tried your code, and it seems that that wasn't the problem (or at least not the only problem?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be multiple things wrong, but one thing for sure is that you are not actually setting the lat/lng for the markers (they are both "1" in your code). Also, you don't need to `find` there once more. The document is already given to you in whole, so you can just take the fields you need:

```
Coordinates.find().observe({
    added: function (document) {
        L.marker({ lat: document.lat,
                   lng: document.lng, }, {
              ...
```

Comment: I still get an error with this code related to an image path not being set, but maybe that's a problem you won't see or know how to fix.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I was referencing the document entries wrongly. Thanks for the assist.